# In SQLite, how to insert an id field in select result?

Tags: sqlite

I know it works with following code in MySQL to achieve such goal:

```
set @n = 0;
select (@n := @n + 1),test_score from test_score where student_name = 'Gao' and test_subject = 'math'
```

In SQLite,there is no variable, so how can I implement similar function in SQLite?
Thanks!

Comment: That's invalid standard SQL. What does this query do?

Comment: I want the select result to be with an increment number field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an `ID` field in your `test_score` table you could just easily add `ORDER BY ID ASC` to your select query.

```
CREATE TABLE test_score (ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, student_name TEXT, test_subject TEXT, score TEXT)
SELECT ID, score FROM test_score WHERE student_name='Gao' AND test_subject='math' ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

NB: by default the query would be ordered by the ID anyway, but in case you would want to switch it to the most recent just replace `ASC` with `DESC`

Comment: but the ID field in select result is not continuous(such as series:1 3 4 7 9 and what I want is 1 2 3 4 5)

Comment: Okay in that case, since SQLite doesn't support native variable syntax u got two choices: you either loop over results with cpp, python or where ever you handle your db request, or you create a temp table in sqlite. Create table temp (id autoincrement...); insert into temp select ... (statement from above without id); select * from temp; drop ttable temp;

Comment: sorry the link seems to be broken.